# Multiple tabs lists: How to show only the content of the clicked tab list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, onclick

I have several tabs that uses the event `on('click')`. That problem is whenever I click a tab that triggers the event it also affects other tabs. How can I prevent it from firing or affecting other tabs.

Here is a sample of the tabs that I'm building on -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs-list li:first').addClass('active'),
    $('.tab-content .show-content:first').addClass('active');
   
   $('.tabs-list li').click(function(e) {
       event.preventDefault();
       if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
           var tabIndex = $(this).index();
           var nthChild = tabIndex + 1;
           
           $('.tabs-list li.active').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');
           $('.tab-content .show-content').removeClass('active');
           $('.tab-content .show-content:nth-child('+ nthChild +')').addClass('active');
       }
   })
})
```

```css
.tabs-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}


.tab-content .show-content {
    display: none
}

.tab-content .show-content.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs-list">
   <li>Tab 1</li>
   <li>Tab 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 1
    </div>
    
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 2
    </div>
    
</div>


<ul class="tabs-list">
   <li>Tab 1</li>
   <li>Tab 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 1
    </div>
    
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 2
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing the event's target node and it's information to make sure you should execute.

i.e.

```
function modalBackgroundClick(e) {
    if (e.target.id == "modalContainer") {
        modalContainer.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

This is checking that you actually clicked a modal background but it should be similar functionality

Answer (score 0):

You have several `.tabs-list` and `.tab-content` in your page so when you use the selectors `$('.tabs-list ...')` and `$('.tab-content ...')`, you are not only selecting the clicked `.tabs-list` and its corresponding `.tab-content` but all the `.tabs-list` and `.tab-content`.

You need to stick with `$(this)` (representing the clicked `.tabs-list`) and select all the other elements from `$(this)`. jQuery provides several helpers to achieve it, like `.parent()`, `.find()` and `.next()`.

Here is a fixed version of your code, using those helpers:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs-list li:first').addClass('active'),
    $('.tab-content .show-content:first').addClass('active');
   
   $('.tabs-list li').click(function(e) {
       event.preventDefault();
       if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
           var tabIndex = $(this).index();
           var nthChild = tabIndex + 1;

           // select the right elements
           var $tabsList = $(this).parent();
           var $tabContent = $tabsList.next('.tab-content');
           
           $tabsList.find('li.active').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');
           $tabContent.find('.show-content').removeClass('active');
           $tabContent.find('.show-content:nth-child('+ nthChild +')').addClass('active');
       }
   })
})
```

```css
.tabs-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}


.tab-content .show-content {
    display: none
}

.tab-content .show-content.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs-list">
   <li>Tab 1</li>
   <li>Tab 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 1
    </div>
    
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 2
    </div>
    
</div>


<ul class="tabs-list">
   <li>Tab 1</li>
   <li>Tab 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 1
    </div>
    
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 2
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your tabs list and tab content. 
Added a data-target attribute for the tabs-list that points to the tabs-content that you want to link the tabs with (or just use next() as GG suggested below)
See adjusted JS accordingly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs-list li:first').addClass('active'),
    $('.tab-content .show-content:first').addClass('active');
   
   $('.tabs-list li').click(function(e) {
       event.preventDefault();
       
       var tabParent =($(e.currentTarget.parentElement)); 
       var targetId = tabParent.data('target');       
       var tabContent = $(targetId);
       
       if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
           var tabIndex = $(this).index();
           var nthChild = tabIndex + 1;
           
           tabParent.find('li.active').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');
           tabContent.find('.show-content').removeClass('active');
           tabContent.find('.show-content:nth-child('+ nthChild +')').addClass('active');
       }
   })
})
```

```css
.tabs-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}


.tab-content .show-content {
    display: none
}

.tab-content .show-content.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs-list"  data-target="#contentContainer1">
   <li>Tab 1</li>
   <li>Tab 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="contentContainer1">
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 1
    </div>
    
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 2
    </div>
</div>


<ul class="tabs-list" data-target="#contentContainer2">
   <li>Tab 1</li>
   <li>Tab 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="contentContainer2">
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 1
    </div>
    
    <div class="show-content">
    Content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

.